# search html div and display results on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

I want to search multiple HTML files from a separate page, where I search for text from all the divs which has a specific id for each, whole id containing  matched search term will be displayed on the search page in list.

The div list looks like this :

```
<body>
    <div class='vs'>
        <div id='header 1'>content 1 here </div>
        <div id='header 2'>another text  </div>
        <div id='header 3'>whatever </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please note that I want to perform search from different page and want to display results there with links to the searchable page.

For now I was searching like this :

**HTML**

```
<body> 
    <input type="text" id='search' />
    <div class='vs'>
        <div id='header 1'>content 1 here </div>
        <div id='header 2'>another text  </div>
        <div id='header 3'>whatever </div>
    </div>   
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#search').on('input', function () {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('.vs div').show();    
    $('.vs div:not(:contains(' + text + '))').hide();
});
```

It is working on the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/5/), but I don't want it to work like this, I want to do the search from a separate page remotely and display results there with link to this page.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What steps have you taken to achieve your goal? The HTML markup you posted offers no help whatsoever.

Comment: You posted the exact same question 6 hours ago: [search from a different html page div's and display results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276319/search-from-a-different-html-page-divs-and-display-results)

Comment: i want to search and list div with matched search terms   from the html page its a ebook  in html actually div id is used for bookmarking purpose in the html ebook

Comment: i was not getting response on the previous question

Comment: The reason you're not getting a response is because you haven't shown that you've put in any effort to try to solve this question yourself. The code you posted is not relevant, and it makes people feel like you're just asking to be spoonfed the code. It's also why you're getting so many downvotes.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/2/  i tried this

Comment: the above code worked acctually i need help displaying same results on seperate page with link to original page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qrFhD/5/

Comment: When you have something like that you should really post it in original post. It helps people get an idea of what you're looking for. I still don't understand what exactly you are looking for though. Can you explain "i need help displaying same results on seperate page with link to original page"? What is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: ok i will keep that in mind right now its searching html file on the same page i want to have a seperate  page that searches from this html file and results will be displayed on that page not in the serchable  original page  with links to the original page

Comment: Have you considered using a MySQL database instead?

Comment: thats the problem cannot use my sql database html from which i have to search has more than 10000 div elements and i need  the results to link to each using anchors

Comment: So are you saying that you didn't create the list in question, but you would like to search from it?

Comment: yes exactly i want to search from the html page remotly

Comment: Hang on, I'll write you an answer.

Comment: thanks a lot i also updated discription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with jQuery and AJAX:

```
<form id="searchForm">
    <input type="text" id="search"/>
    <input type="submit" name="Search!" />
</form>
<div id="resultContainer">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#searchForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var results = $("#resultContainer");
        var text = $("#search").val();
        results.empty();
        $.get("http://example.com/", function(data) {
            results.append($(data).find("div:contains(" + text + ")"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d64np/) (This fiddle enables you to search for content on the jsfiddle page, try for example `JSFiddle` as search term.)

Note however that this does not work cross-domain, because browsers will prevent cross-site scripting. You didn't describe your use-case clear enough for me to know whether you're okay with that.

Comment: Sure. Instead of just appending the `div`s that have been found, use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on them and add the link to each one before appending it to the results. You can get the id for creating the link with `.attr("id")`.

Comment: I have to  search from around 6000 div so adding links manually will be a pain can i do this by javascript side

Comment: My instructions were about doing this with JavaScript. Please try implementing it yourself - StackOverflow is for help with problems you run into, we won't just implement stuff for you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kd6Y4/1/  its working now here managed to write hyperlinks as well but its not working offline please help

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at using PHP `file_get_contents` to retrieve the HTML contents of the external page, and from there analyze the data in the `<div>`s that you are interested in. Ultimately, you'll want to store each individual search term in a JavaScript array (you can create JavaScript arrays dynamically using PHP), and then create search functionality similar to example you posted to search all the elements in your array.

So on page load, you'll want to have a `<div>` in which you are going to list all the elements from the array. You can list these by looping through the array and displaying each individual element. From there, you will want to call a function every time the user enters or deletes a character in the `<input>` box. This function will update the `<div>` with an updated list of elements that match the string in the `<input>` box.

This is the theory behind what you are trying to accomplish. Hopefully it will give you some direction as to how to write your code.

**Update:**

If you're looking for a JavaScript only solution, check out a JavaScript equivalent of PHP's `file_get_contents`: http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/

From here, you can maybe look at using `.split` to break up the list. Ultimately, you're still trying to store each individual search term as an element in an array, it's just the method that you retrieve these terms is different (JavaScript as opposed to PHP).

Perhaps I *was* emphasizing too much on PHP, perhaps it's because it's the web development language I'm most familiar with. Hope this JavaScript-only solution is helpful.

Comment: can i do this without using php ? because i have to use this totally offline using java-script and html itself no php environment

Comment: If you have an apache server with PHP installed on your computer and both files locally stored, you can still do this offline. It should be achievable with JavaScript as long as both files are on your domain. Take a look at http://phpjs.org/

Comment: yes both files are on directory its will not be hosted in domain but will be stored offline for a hybrid application across multiple devices  so cannot acctually use php any idea where exactly i should dig to get it using javascript and recommendation of plugins ??

Comment: As I said before, you can host it on the localhost. Just because the files are stored on your local computer doesn't mean that you are restricted to only HTML and JavaScript. As I said before, look at http://phpjs.org, but I'm not seeing why you can't use PHP.

Comment: because i also have to use same files in a hybrid android app and a ios app etc in webview

Comment: So? PHP is server-side, it doesn't matter which type of browser (mobile or desktop) you load it on.

Comment: I think you're advertising PHP too much here, goddfree. He asked for a solution in JavaScript.

Comment: i guss i got a solution i just made this work using jquery 1.4.2 but its not running on many browsers and mobile devices but is running on pc if you can help me achieve this

Comment: I updated my post to include a JavaScript solution. Perhaps I was advertising PHP too much.

Comment: thanks i am looking at that i will post here if that works or i get a solution